# %w in ruby makes code not work?

Tags: ruby, string

Please compare the 2 codes (the first returning the correct value of false while the second returns a value of true) The only difference in the codes is the %w. Why does the %w cause this problem?

```
#1
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  letters_arr = word.split("")
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end

ordered_vowel_word?("complicated")

#2
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = %w[a, e, i, o, u]
   letters_arr = word.split("")
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
  vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end



ordered_vowel_word?("complicated")
```

Comment: Did you consider looking at the value of `vowels` once you set it???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using it with commas. That is half the purpose of using this notation. Correctly:

```
%w[a e i o u]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
vowels = %w[a e i o u]
```

Commas are not needed.

```
irb(main):001:0> %w[a, e, i, o, u]
=> ["a,", "e,", "i,", "o,", "u"]
irb(main):002:0> %w[a e i o u]
=> ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
```

As you can see, `%w` will treat its contents as a string and split by space.